# How do i output a user input string

Tags: lc3

I'm very new to LC-3 assembly language, Currently doing an assignment, One of the questions I am asked is to output a user input string, for example:

```
Please enter a text: Hello world123

The text you have entered is: Hello world123
```

Here is the Code that I have been using:

```
.orig x3000

Lea r0, Name

Puts

Lea r0, inputstring

Puts

lea r2, outputstring

loop

getc

add r1,r0, -10

brz outside

out

str r0,r2, #0

add r2, r2, #1

brnzp loop

outside 

lea r0, output_text

puts

Halt

Name .stringz "Francois Van Zyl"

inputstring .stringz "\nPlease enter a text: "

output_text .stringz "\nThe text you have typed is: "

outputstring .blkw 99

.end
```

I expect that after the user inputted a string, the program would show the result. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I finally found it! by experimenting a lot. 
here is the code I have done:**

```
.orig   x3000
Lea r1, storeString

Lea r0, Student
puts

Lea r0, Userinput
puts

LOOP
getc

out
str r0, r1, 0
add r1, r1, 1
add r0, r0, -10

brz OUTSIDE

brnzp LOOP

OUTSIDE

Lea r0, Outputtext
puts

Lea r0, storeString
puts

Halt
Student .stringz "Francois Van Zyl"
Userinput .stringz "\n\nPlease enter a text: "
Outputtext .stringz "The text you have typed is: "
storeString .blkw 99

.end
```